# Slight mysql insert query error

Tags: mysql, sql

Importing from one table to another.. this errors.

```
INSERT INTO wp_users (DEFAULT, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_status, display_name)
SELECT ID, username, password, LOWER(username), email, company_url, date_added, '0', username
FROM user
WHERE ID BETWEEN 5000 to 10000;
```

I just don't want the ID inserted as it's auto-incremented in `wp_users` so I'm using "DEFAULT".

> Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'DEFAULT, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email,
>   user_url, user_regist' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT`, `user` are reserved words in MySQL,  escape them. Also the predicate `BETWEEN` should be `BETWEEN ... AND ...` not `BETWEEN ... TO ...`:

```
INSERT INTO wp_users (`DEFAULT`, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_status, display_name)
SELECT ID, username, password, LOWER(username), email, company_url, date_added, '0', username
FROM `user`
WHERE ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000;
```

Comment: Thanks, but still errors :( `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to 10000' at line 4`

Comment: @Dave `user` also a reserved word, escape it.

Comment: @Dave Sorry again, it is `WHERE ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000;` not `WHERE ID BETWEEN 5000 to 10000;`

Comment: No problem! Now a new error haha `#1054 - Unknown column 'DEFAULT' in 'field list'`

Comment: Do I need to even insert ID of default? Can't I just remove it from `insert` and `select` as it's auto-incremented?

Comment: @Dave - OK, so you don't want the `ID` inserted into the table `wp_users` as it's auto-incremented, do you want to insert the value from the other table? or the default value?

Comment: Then make the field as an auto-incremental and enter the "" instead of 'DEFAULT'.

Comment: Errors with `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"", user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered,' at line 1`

Comment: @Dave Is this field defined as an `auto_incremental` in the table structure?

Comment: Yep it is. Can I just use NULL to use auto-increment

Comment: `1  ID  bigint(20)   UNSIGNED  No  None  AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @Dave - I am working on that, just give me some minutes please. Sorry.

Comment: It's ok I just did this.. `INSERT INTO wp_users (user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_status, display_name)
SELECT username, password, LOWER(username), email, company_url, date_added, '0', username
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.ID BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000;`